# C# input validation to SQL using Datasets multiple forms

Tags: c#, sql, dataset

We're using Datasets to turn input in a form from a Textbox into the database (part of the exam we're getting monday), there are 6 forms where basically the same is done but it's different textboxes and different forms for the different tables. I can obviously use If's and Try{} Catch{} to validate the input, but that would mean I have to make it for every single form. Since we're using Datasets is there anyway to validate the input in an easier way? It's basically formConfiguration.cs and then datasetConfiguration made with the dataSources setup from Visual Studio itself. The application is already made and it's our job to put validation in and add a extra form. So is there a nice way to check them nice and easy and give proper feedback about why there was an error? MessageBox.Show("Reason of error here"); or do I have to use if's/TryCatch in every single form?

I can't really give example of code because everything is on a Virtual Machine @ school and we're obviously not allowed to take the code/assignments with us to home, although we're allowed to discuss it.

Comment: To communicate between form(s) you need to use an instance of a form.  See my earlier posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net/34975678#comment57681005_34975678

Comment: I'm sorry how would I use this to take textboxes from 6 forms and check all the data at once? While every textbox requires a different kind of check to make sure it doesn't give a SQL error?

Comment: The only way of verifying that the value of the textbox is valid is perform a query of the database.  You need to be able to get the value of the textboxes from each of the forms and pass the value to the form where the query is being executed.

Comment: They're just Textboxes with the right Databinding assigned to each of them, so all I use is the .Update() method. Throwing a TryCatch around that doesn't really allow me to give feedback about what kind of issue it is.

Comment: Using an instance of the forms you can pass status between forms or display an error message in the main form.  Look at the method GetData() in my sample project.